# How to access celery task's response from a queue

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have an app `A` and an app `W` (the worker).
`A` send tasks to `W` using Celery (and redis as backend and broker), however A needs to get every result back (as soon as they are available).

My first idea was to use a data structure in `A` storing every pending tasks

```py
class ResponseQueue:

    def __init__(self):
        self.done = set()
        self.pending = set()


    def add_task(self, task):
        """
        Add a task to the queue
        """
        self.pending.add(task)

    def check_all_states(self):
        """
        Check all states of the tasks in the queue.
        If a previously pending task is now ready, add it to the `done` set.
        """
        for state in self.pending:
            if state.ready():
                self.done.add(state)
                self.pending.remove(state)

    def pick_one(self):
        """
        Return an unprocessed response
        """
        return self.done.pop()
```

Then the processing loop in `A` would be like that:

```py
while True:
    response_queue.check_all_states()
    resp = response_queue.pick_one()
    process(resp)
```

However this solution is not optimal because `ResponseQueue.check_all_states` must check every pending task's state

Is there a way to directly pick an element from all the succeeded tasks, without checking every states ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: As far as I know you need to poll for results. Maybe using Group will be more convenient, as GroupResult has some useful properties...

Comment: Another idea is to use `A` as a worker: when `W` is done processing a task, it create a `process_response` task and send it to the client `A`. I'm not sure if it is possible to have 2 interdependent celery workers